# What do I use for summary file when publishing code coverage results in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, cobertura

Unfortunately imgur is blocked here at my workplace, so instead of screenshots of my build definition I will have to explain my build definition settings to the best of my ability.

I have two build steps, the first is a maven build step that runs the "package" goal.  Under the code coverage section of the maven settings I have the CodeCoverage Tool set as "Cobertura", which is what we use on our local boxes when maven building.

My second build step is "Publish Code Coverage Results".  I am not sure exactly what to put for my summary file in the settings of this build step. I think that the problem is that the build agent takes the cobertura folder off of the build machine and puts it somewhere else not on the build machine.  This is the log entry for what it is doing:

`Uploaded artifact 'C:\TFS_BUILD_AGENTS\agent-1\_work\3\s\target\site\cobertura' to container folder 'Code Coverage Report_35241' of build 35241.`

So I either need the Summary File location for wherever it is uploading to, or I need to have it not upload the folder like it is currently doing.

This is what I have as the summary file right now, which does not work:

`Code Coverage Report_$(Build.BuildId)\coverage.xml`

Comment: Is there any feedback and did you checked, or has it been solved?

Comment: Is the code coverage report generated during the Maven step? Can you share the entire logs?

Answer (score 0):

You could check in this file to TFS and map it down to the build agent server. Then you could some build variables(like `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` which represents 'C:\TFS_BUILD_AGENTS\agent-1_work\3\s') to get the file. 
So you need to put `C:\TFS_BUILD_AGENTS\agent-1\_work\3\...\***.xml`. Make sure the file is located at the path your specified.

If the file you want to upload is generated after the step1, please check which path is locates and point it in the [Summary file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PublishCodeCoverageResults/README.md) blanket.